# How can I use an exception to allow only a string binary input of 0s and 1s and reject everything else?

Tags: python, exception, while-loop, binary

This is my code and I'm not allowed to use built in functions to convert bin to decimal. I have to implement try and except in this but have tried and failed.

I need the input to only accept 1s and 0s. I need to display an error message and have the user try again if anything else is inputted.

```
`#Declaration
strBinaryNumber= ""
intBinaryLength= 0
strBinaryInput= ""
intDecimalNumber= 0`

`#User input of binary number
strBinaryNumber= input("Enter your binary number: ")
intBinaryLength= len(strBinaryNumber)
strBinaryInput= strBinaryNumber`


`#Loop count for decimal conversion
intDecimalNumber = 0
while len(strBinaryNumber) > 0:
   intDecimalNumber*=2
    intDecimalNumber+= int(strBinaryNumber[0])
    strBinaryNumber = strBinaryNumber[1:]`



`#Decimal Output
print("\nThe binary number is:", strBinaryInput)
print("\nThe length is:", intBinaryLength)
print("\nYour decimal number is:", intDecimalNumber)`
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: Write down the steps to take in human language first, so that everyone (even a non-programmer) can follow the steps and reach a proper result. Then, put the whole thing in code. Note that you may not really need to use exceptions for that, other flow control mechanisms are enough as well. Finally, think whether there's a place where exceptions could be used. That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, don't expect people here to do your homework.

Comment: I don't expect anyone to do my homework I did all the work I just am not able to put a try and except without failure and I think all it has to do with is location. Does it go before the loop? or before the input? If I put it before the input then I can't reference the input so I put it after right before the loop and I still get an error

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of a try-except statement is that if the code could fail, there’s something to prevent it from breaking.

try:
      (code you want to run)
  except:
      (code to run if the earlier code fails)

if you put this in a function then make it call the function again from the except statement if the code fails that might help.

Is this what you meant?

Comment: That would be a recursive call then, but for no apparent reason. A good reason against it is that it can overflow the stack.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt what if the recursion depth was noted in order to ensure it didn’t exceed a certain depth. I wouldn’t use a try-except statement either, it just sounded like that was what the question was asking for. That said, is there any harm in using a recursive call in this situation provided some manner of avoiding an overflow of a stack is avoided? Or would it be better to simply repeat in a loop until the user is successful?

Comment: I am trying to make my user input only accept 0s and 1s no letters and no other integers and to give an error, try again when something invalid is entered. We haven't learned recursion in class so I can't use it and the professor asked us to complete this with a try-except. I put try: and put in my user input statement then except ValueError: and printed an input statement that said try again. I don't see anything wrong with my code but it didn't work. The assignment is not graded so I'm not trying to get anyone to do my homework just trying to understand.